# Portainer no puedo unirme a una red existente

Tags: docker

estoy configurando un template en Portainer para levantar un sistema que tenemos para varios departamentos del trabajo.

El problema que estoy teniendo es que debo compartir la base de datos y no logro hacer que se unan automaticamente a la red, me crea una nueva y debo cambiarla manualmente.

```html
version: '2'

networks:
  soporte:

services:
   backend:
    image: back:latest
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mysql
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_PASS=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:-Jfsd498SD4d4SD564D}
      - DB_NAME=${MYSQL_DATABASE:-soporte}
      - JWT_SECRET=${JWT_SECRET:-00000000}
      - JWT_REFRESH_SECRET=${JWT_REFRESH_SECRET:-111111}
      - BACKEND_URL=${BACKEND_URL:-http://192.168.1.163}
      - FRONTEND_URL=${FRONTEND_URL:-http://192.168.1.163:23000}
      - PROXY_PORT=${PROXY_PORT:-24000}
      - CHROME_ARGS=--no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox
    ports:
      - ${BACKEND_PORT:-24000}:3000
    volumes:
      - ./backend/public/:/usr/src/app/public/
      - ./backend/.wwebjs_auth/:/usr/src/app/.wwebjs_auth/
    networks:
      - soporte
      
   frontend:
    image: front:latest
    ports:
      - ${FRONTEND_PORT:-23000}:80
      - ${FRONTEND_SSL_PORT:-23001}:443
    environment:
      - URL_BACKEND=192.168.1.163:3000
      - REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL=${BACKEND_URL:-http://192.168.1.163}:${PROXY_PORT:-24000}/
      - FRONTEND_SERVER_NAME=${FRONTEND_SERVER_NAME}
      - BACKEND_SERVER_NAME=${BACKEND_SERVER_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ./ssl/certs/:/etc/nginx/ssl/
      - ./ssl/www/:/var/www/letsencrypt/
    networks:
      - soporte
```

Yo lo que estoy haciendo es lo siguiente, cree las imagenes, cree el template que es el siguiente... y cada vez que debo dar de alta un departamento... voy a custom templates...
Cambio el nombre por ejemplo a "legales". y en el template cambio los puertos que va a utilizar esta nueva instalación.

y le doy a Deploy Stack... y listo todo funcionando... el problema es que me crea otra red llamada legales_soporte... en lugar de unirse a la que esta actualmente funcionando que es soporte, en donde esta corriendo la db de MySQL.

Debo ir al contenedor y cambiar manualmente la red por soporte, y ahi todo se conecta sin problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Pude solucionar mi problema de la siguiente manera:

```
version: '2'

networks:
  default:
    name: soporte
    external: true
```

para setear de forma global la network